# Is it possible to disable Sidecar in macOS or iOS?

Tags: macos, sidecar

Is it possible to disable the Sidecar feature on macOS or iOS? I never use it and will sometime accidentally select "Move to [iPad]" when trying to move a window to my other monitor and it locks up my Mac until it timeouts trying to connect to the iPad.